# Vertical scrolling gallery for joomla

Tags: image, joomla, module, popup, gallery

I need module for joomla 2.5.4 - vertical image carousel (3-4 images in column) with navigation and with lightboxes when you click on image (navigation in popup window). Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need --

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/slideshow/image-mootools-slideshow/13119

OR check this---

http://www.demo2.ari-soft.com/joomla-carousel-module.html

Comment: @PramodKumarSharma u cant always run in safe zone

Comment: Thank you. But this is not so. I'm looking something like this http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_vertical.html

Comment: @PramodKumarSharma: if its conflicting, edit the PHP file that gets the jquery library and replace with the code on [this tutorial](http://joomjunk.co.uk/extra/tutorials/joomla-tutorials/jquery-conflicts-in-joomla.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use this module http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/news-tickers-a-scrollers/15315 this will works for you, you can also check demo of this module at http://demo.themexpert.com/extensions/free-extensions/xpert-scroller

Comment: Thank you. But this is not exactly what I'm looking. I'm going to make such module myself